# Angularjs elements not found with selenium - Java

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I need to getText from a specific element from the page and these elements only have unique tag "ng-bind="$Gadget.customerSegmentation" and also element location may be changed according to the scenario

I tried below for finding elements but sometimes it working not sometimes no.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@ng-bind='$Gadget.customerSegmentation']")
WebElement Customer;

<div class="form_group inline_block" style="width:30%;"> 
  <div class="form_label ng-binding" style="width:30%;">Cust Segmentation:</div> 
   <div class="form_control ng-binding" title="Low" ng-bind="$Gadget.customerSegmentation" style="width:65%;float:right;">Low</div>  
                </div>
```

can found elements even if the location changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  @FindBy(css  = "div.form_control.ng-binding[title='Low'][ng-bind$='customerSegmentation']")
  WebElement Customer;
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='form_control ng-binding' and @title='Low'][contains(@ng-bind, 'customerSegmentation')]")
  WebElement Customer;
  ```

Comment: working fine with me but after removing title as it change according to scenario thanks you alooot :)